# AIDL vs JAR/AAR

Tags: android

I'm currently a junior developer. I've heard about IPC and now I'm learning about Android AIDL.

I've made an `.aidl` file, I've implemented the methods from that `.aidl` in a Service and I've used those methods in another application, but I don't see the point.

Why I cannot just make an `.aar` or a `.jar` file containing that Service, without using AIDL? When I should use AIDL and when I should import `.jar` files. More general, what is the point of using IPC when we can work with `.jar` files?

Comment: IPC means InterProcessCommunication, so you are using `AIDL` when you want to pass some data between two different applications or if the both sides are in the same app but are hosted by different processes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why I cannot just make an .aar or a .jar file containing that Service, without using AIDL?

From documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html:

> Using AIDL is necessary only if you allow clients from different applications to access your service for IPC and want to handle multithreading in your service.

When you pack a `Service` in aar or jar this service can run anywhere, i.e. either in the same or in a different process of an application. AIDL is specifically designed for IPC, that is, service and app in different processes.

> More general, what is the point of using IPC when we can work with .jar files?

IPC is a operating system provided data sharing mechanism and jar is a bytecode distribution means. They are different things.

Suppose you want to consume a service provided by someone, and that you don't have its source nor its bytecode. You can only access this service in runtime, in a process managed by the provider, different than your own. In this case you'll need an AIDL specified by the provider in order to communicate with the service.

Comment: Thank you! This was very informative :). By the way, in the last part of the comment you said "You can only access this service in runtime, in a process managed by the provider". Can you recommend me some articles about this stuff?

Comment: @MateutAlin i don't know if there are any articles about it :( it's just a specific case i assembled. The documentation i linked and Services guide should cover the subject: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Ok. Thank you anyway for the answer.